# Machine Learning Predict Precision

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision, machine-learning

I have this code

```
p = Predict[{1 -> 123456789123456789, 3 -> 987654321987654321}]
```

values are big, more than 15 digits (standard machine precision).

when I try to call predictor function like this

```
p[4] // AccountingForm
```

I get this error message

```
AccountingForm::reqsigz: Requested number precision is lower than number of digits shown; padding with zeros.
```

and this value as a result

```
987654321987654000
```

As I see last 3 digits are lost.

if I do like this

```
p = Predict[{1 -> 123456789123456789`50, 3 -> 987654321987654321`50}]
```

result is the same.

My question is:

Is it possible to force Mathematica to increase precision for Predict function and avoid digit losses? WorkingPrecision parameter does not work for predict.